# crystal reports 10, asp classic, iis 7.5: http error 401

Tags: asp-classic, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

I have an ancient report written using Crystal Reports < 10 (it should be version 8 or 9) currently filled by an ASP classic application depending on Crystal Engine 10; the application is hosted on a Windows Server 2003 R2 machine that must be upgraded so I have to move the application while waiting for it to be rewritten.

The application itself is running ok on the new server (Win 2008 R2/IIS 7.5, this specific version is a requirement), only the reports are broken, show no data at all, nothing on the screen but report controls (zoom, send, print, export); the odd thing is that I can export the report as PDF and once downloaded open it and read the expected data.

Using developer tools of IE I notice that the ASP page called by the CR component to load the data (the file is `RDCrptserver10.asp`) fails to load with a `401` authentication error message for no apparent reason: the page is in the same folder as the other pages that I browse to make the report load and has the very same permission of the other pages.

Trying to access the url of that page directly (cut & paste from developer tool into browser bar) IE produces a generic error message 'page unavailable' and not a `401` error.

Moreover in both cases (direct url access and rtp load) the IIS log has a `200` success entry (yes, IIS say that the page was shipped successfully in both cases).

I'm stuck because after checking all that comes to my mind I can't have the report to work on the new server.

**My checks and attempts:**
- odbc data source: the name is correct, tested user & pass working ok. also should the source be broken i would not be able to download the file as PDF with actual and up to date data
- path of files: there are no `404` errors, double checked that required files are in place and accessible
- completely removed authentication for the folder containing the relevant files (the app is in a company intranet with integrated windows authentication) but still get a `401` error when loading the report
- checked the ntfs and iis permission of the involved files
- double checked the software version of the crystal engine to be the same currently installed on the old server
- the component called by the ASP page to load the report exists on the server
- there is no error in the event viewer

Does anyone experienced similar issues with crystal/asp on iis 7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue in a really unexpected way: some  `Response.Flush()` dropped here and there in the `RDCrptserver10.asp` page allowed the report to be filled successfully on the new server.

the old code running successfully since ages is:

```
Response.AddHeader "CONTENT-LENGTH", lenb(temp)
Response.ContentType = EPFMIMETYPE
Response.BinaryWrite temp
```

to make it run on the new server it has to be changed as follows:

```
Response.AddHeader "CONTENT-LENGTH", lenb(temp)
Response.ContentType = EPFMIMETYPE
Response.BinaryWrite temp
Response.Flush
```

in the above page there are many block similar to that one with minor variation in parameters and/or ContentType depending on the different input but adding a flush after each BinaryWrite fixed the issue, 401 failure and all.

I'm still puzzled by the 401 error but at least now it works...